# Framer-Motion animations work in dev mode but not in build mode (nextjs)

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

When i run my website with `next dev` the animations work as expected, but when i build it with `next build` and run with `next start` the styling of the text that should be animated is not applied anymore so instead of the text zooming out in the center it zooms out in the top left corner (Exit animation). [https://zzir.vercel.app/](https://stackoverflow.com).

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import type {AppProps} from 'next/app'
import Layout from "./layout";
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
import {AnimatePresence, motion} from 'framer-motion';

export default function App({Component, pageProps}: AppProps) {
const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <Layout>
            <AnimatePresence mode={"wait"}>
                <motion.div
                    key={router.route}
                    initial="pageInitial"
                    animate="pageAnimate"
                    exit="pageExit"
                    variants={{
                        pageInitial: {
                            opacity: 0,
                            scale: 0.9,
                        },
                        pageAnimate: {
                            opacity: 1,
                            scale: 1,
                            transition: {
                                duration: 0.5,
                            },
                        },
                        pageExit: {
                            opacity: 0,
                            scale: 0.9,
                            transition: {
                                duration: 0.5,
                            },
                        },
                    }}
                >
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </motion.div>
            </AnimatePresence>
        </Layout>
    )

}
```

I've tried removing the exit animation alltogether, changing the AnimatePresence mode, but the issue only seems to go away when I removed the whole AnimatePresence.